# SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have written following code.

```
declare @a int
set @a=select count(*) from Patient
print @a
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally use set if you want to assign value for one variable only and  use select for multiple variables....

see below examples..

```
declare @a int
set @a=(select count(*) from sales.orders)
print @a


declare @cnt int,@dt datetime

select @cnt=count(*) ,@dt=max(orderdate) from sales.orders
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @a int 

select @a = count(*) from Patient 
^^^^^^

print @a
```

Comment: so whats another solution to it

Comment: that comment makes no sense. I've posted the solution to your question.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but i got the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `SET`, then you have to enclose the `SELECT` statement in parenthesis:

```
DECLARE @a INT 

SET @a = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patient) 

PRINT @a
```

Comment: @akshaysutar Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.